# Websocket handshake over SSL TIMEOUT

Tags: websocket, lets-encrypt, shared-hosting, ratchet, php-socket

I have my website running on **shared hosting over https(Using Let's Encrypt)**. It implements websocket using Ratchet as below

```
$pusher = new qApp\Pusher;

 $loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
    $context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
    $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
    $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
    $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onNewCall'));

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:1234', $loop); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
    $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                    $pusher
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );

    $loop->run();
```

When client tried connecting

```
 var socket  = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1234');
```

**on localhost , it works fine.**

But when same is tried on web server using wss

```
 var socket  = new WebSocket('wss://domainname.com:1234');
```

**It TIMEOUTS after 15-20 secs .** Is there anything i am missing in implementing.

Comment: `$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself` did you forget to change this? Is your port open for incoming connections? Is the domain acting as a proxy between the client and server? Does the domain allow for connections through port 1234? Normally SSL connections are done through pre-defined ports.

Comment: Actually i have a rest api hosted and web socket server running, so i used ZMQ to pass data from REST api to sokcet using $pull ( ZMQContext).Currently have no role of $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); .  Blocked on first step of client connection. I tried same on port 8080 also, but no success. Are there any other defined ports for wss ?